# jquery - Using autocomplete trying to retrieve key and value from DB returns a grey pulldown menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

Not sure what is going on or what I am missing but for some reason when using autocomplete and trying to retrieve a `$key` and `$value` so I can list the `value` in the dropdown and use the `ID` to of that value the pulldown is completely grey and I cannot select anything. Here is an example.

[image]

**jquery**

```
$(document).on('focus', 'div.form-group-options div.input-group-option:last-child input', function(){
    var sInputGroupHtml = $(this).parent().html();
    var sInputGroupClasses = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    var sInputGroupId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).parent().parent().append('<div class="'+sInputGroupClasses+'">'+sInputGroupHtml+'</div>');
    $('.searchsong').autocomplete({
        source:'../includes/searchaddsong.php',
        minLength:0,
    });
});
```

**searchaddsong.php**

```
$key=$_GET['term'];
$sql = "SELECT ID,title FROM wafilepaths WHERE title LIKE '%{$key}%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

if I change mysql to `$array[] = $row['title'];` then I get the values in the pulldown, but I need the ID as well so I can reference the record.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: If possible, can include `css` ? , create stacksnippets , http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autocomplete needs to be in one of two formats. A standard index array, or in format

```
[
    {
         label:"something",
         value: "something"
    },
    ....

]
```

Yours has `title` and something else. Just map `title` and `id` to `label` and `value` in php.

```
$row['label'] = $row['title'];
$row['value'] = $row['id']; //or whatever this field was
$rows[] = $row;
```

Comment: It can be in pure HTML also.

Comment: @phpPluginMaster Why the down vote?  My answer actually relates to the guys question.  This isnt the jquery docs page.

Comment: You lied to them, because you can output it in HTML format like so: https://github.com/FREE-FROM-CMS/AutoComplete/